# Android Studio: disabled Active Editor settings keep resetting (using ideavim also)

Tags: android, ideavim

So in Android Studio, I want to have as much space as possible available for editing code. I don't need breadcrumbs, don't need line numbers, don't need gutter icons. It's all so much fluff to me and I want the pixels back.

I disable the options in Active Editor, but they keep reappearing.

One wrinkle, I am using ideavim . I have 'set noshowmode' in my ideavimrc for those who know what that means.

I am able to uncheck the boxes in 'Active Editor' and get the sidebars to go away:

[image: without]

However as I open and close tabs they reappear:

[image: with]

And I have to uncheck all the stuffs again.

Any suggestions welcome -- thanks !

Comment: An update, removing ideavim plugin fixes this problem. So looks like a bug in the interaction between ideavim and Android Studio. I should check if it's also happening in IntelliJ.

Comment: This is a bit weird and I can't reproduce this issue. Are sure that this behavior appears if you enable IdeaVim again?
BTW, have you checked https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/ide-viewing-modes.html?section=Windows%20or%20Linux#distraction_free?

Comment: thanks for the suggestions ... will give it a shot.